# Is there a way to delete the response to an interaction (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently started converting my commands to slash commands. I successfully did that, but I'm missing one functionality that I can't seem to find how to do. I want to delete the response I've given to an interaction (so the callback), and if possible after a certain amount of time (but that isn't required for my Discord bot).

For example, my callback is posted like this:

```js
client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
   data: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
         content: 'Hello World!'
      }

   }
})
```

And I want to delete that response immediately (or timed, but not in this example).

In the Discord docs ([this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#followup-messages) page) is standing that it is possible, but I don't know how exactly to do that.
The specific code I already tried is this, but when the code is executed I'm getting the `METHOD NOT ALLOWED` error:

```js
client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.delete()
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

*Sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Support for `client.api` will not be provided. Its for private reasons.

Comment: @Radnerus, I have not given any personal information and this is just a question like another, or am I wrong? I'm just asking how to do something in general without giving away any sensitive information at all, and trying to get help with an error I'm getting, that's all...

Comment: You have not included your code which you claim to produce a "method not allowed" result.

Comment: @ApocalypseCalculator, maybe I did not make it clear enough, my bad . The code I used is the second code snippet inserted into my question, but I'll put it here too:
`client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.delete()`. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @RuneVandenHeuvel I believe commands are not fully supported by Discord.js. Try using a direct HTTP DELETE request to the endpoint (check out the docs you linked)

Comment: @ApocalypseCalculator, thanks for the info! I tested it out and that worked. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just fetch this :
[https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/{APP ID}/{Interaction Token}/messages/@original](https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/%7BAPP%20ID%7D/%7BInteraction%20Token%7D/messages/@original)

Like That :

> fetch(`"https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/123456789012345678/${interaction.token}/messages/@original"`,
> {
> method: "DELETE"
> }
> );

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#delete-original-interaction-response

Comment: Thanks! I've found the solution myself but this is exactly what I did so this is the solution...