# Is there a way to delete the response of a slash command [Discord.js]

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My code is:

```
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
        const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
        const args = interaction.data.options;

        if (command === 'test'){ 
        console.log("Test executed")
        
        client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
            data: {
                type: 4,
                data: {
                    content: "Check"
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I want to delete the answer but I don't really understand how (Very new to this discord.js thing xd)

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67162176/is-there-a-way-to-delete-the-response-to-an-interaction-discord-js) but can't make the answer work

Can anybody please help :(

EDIT: Is it also possible to have a cooldown for a slash command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a reply to an interaction (according to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#delete-original-interaction-response)) with discord.js v12 use the following:

```js
client.api.webhooks(client.user.id, interaction.token)
    .messages("@original").delete();
```

> Is it also possible to have a cooldown for a slash command?

Yes, it is definitely possible. It should be very similar to cooldowns for non-slash commands. Here you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432168/9776840) post, very simple cooldown system. Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634893/discord-js-command-cooldown-is-set-but-not-working) you have something more complex.

Here you can have a look at my **simple and far from perfect** example concerning cooldown system for slash commands:

```js
const cooldowns = new Set();

client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", (interaction) => {

    const userId = interaction.member.user.id;
    const commandName = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
    
    const cooldownId = `${commandName}_${userId}`;
    const cooldownDuration = 60000; // 60 000 ms = 1 minute

    if (cooldowns.has(cooldownId)) {
        // There is a cooldown, notify user and return
        client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
            data: {
                type: 4,
                data: {
                    content: "Wait 1 minute before typing this again!",
                    flags: 64, // make reply ephemeral
                }
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    // Create cooldown for next use
    cooldowns.add(cooldownId);
    setTimeout(() => { // Schedule cooldown deletion
        cooldowns.delete(cooldownId);
    }, cooldownDuration);

    // ... Execute the command ...

});
```

Comment: Oh nice, that worked thx a lot, any idea about the cooldown by any chance?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can take a look.

Comment: I have also added an example. Consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark, if you think it answered your question.

Comment: With the example I acheived why I wanted, only issue now is that 
```client.api.webhooks(client.user.id, interaction.token)
.messages("@original").delete();```
it drops an error... I try to delete the message for the cooldown, so if the sender spam the /check command he will not have a lot of the "Wait 1 minute...." message

Comment: Don't make the message [ephemeral](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000580222-Ephemeral-Messages-FAQ) then, remove the `flags` property. Ephemeral messages are deleted automatically after some period of time or when you restart discord or click the "Dismiss" button. They are also private.